# Why is the Ramond vacuum a Majorana fermion in type II string theory?

Tags: string-theory, vacuum, spinors, majorana-fermions

I understand that in order to have a supersymmetric spectrum in string theory, the vacuum has to be a MW (Majorana-Weyl) spinor under $SO(1,9)$. But I don't see where the Majorana condition on the R vacuum comes from. I understand that the GSO projection chooses a chirality, so that the R vacuum is a Weyl spinor, but I don't see why it should also be Majorana (aside from rendering the spectrum supersymmetric).

I think it may go along the lines of requiring MW spinors on the world-sheet to have world-sheet supersymmetry, and the Majorana condition translates to spacetime, but again I'm still quite new to the field and translating world-sheet properties to space-time is still difficult.

Comment: My understanding is that we do indeed impose it to match the number of DOF in NS and R sector ground states to get spacetime SUSY, as you mentioned.